# When I distribute a table with DISTSTYLE ALL in Redshift, how do slices on each compute node account for DISTSTYLE ALL'd table's disk space?

Tags: amazon-redshift

From [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html), it says that when I use DISTSTYLE ALL, the table gets distributed to each compute node. It's not clear how each of the slices on each compute node handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...DISTSTYLE to ALL, all the rows are distributed to the first slice of each node.

I found the answer on a different page of documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Distribution_examples.html

Comment: The next interesting question here would be: why only to the first slice of each node ?